# Android Studio 3.1.2 keyboard stops working after creating Add to Git dialog dismissed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

This issue has been happening since around a week ago on Android Studio 3.1.2 (currently the latest stable version), on a Mac with High Sierra 10.13.5.

**How to reproduce**

1. Open a project that use Git
2. Create a new Java class (I haven't tried other file types)
3. When the "add to Git" dialog appears, press **either** Ok or Cancel
4. Enjoy your lack of cursor and frozen keyboard.

An obvious workaround was to not click Ok or Cancel, and instead click outside of the dialog. However, lately the issue happens even in this way, although it takes longer to occur, and the only way I found to recover from this was to restart Android Studio altogether.

What else can I do about this besides downgrading Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

This annoying bug is gone at least as of AS 3.2.1